# slick returning a dictionaries object from database

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to select from a few tables and put their results in an Object. I want to do this because those are dictionaries and I want all of them at startup.

This is what I have right now:

Controller:

```
  def getDictionaries = Action.async { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(dictionaryService.getDictionaries)))
  }
```

DictionaryService:

```
  override def getDictionaries : Dictionaries = {
    val currencies: Future[Seq[Currency]] = dictionaryDao.getCurrencies
    val propertyTypes: Future[Seq[PropertyType]] = dictionaryDao.getPropertyTypes
    Dictionaries(
      currencies.result(Duration(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)),
      propertyTypes.result(Duration(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    )
  }
```

DictionaryDAO:

```
  override def getCurrencies: Future[Seq[Currency]] = {
    db.run(slickCurrencies.result)
  }
  ... getPropertyTypes ...
```

Dictionaries case class and companion object

```
case class Dictionaries (currencies: Seq[Currency], propertyTypes: Seq[PropertyType])

object Dictionaries {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Dictionaries]
}
```

I am not very proud of `currencies.result(Duration(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` but I am not sure what I should retrieve from this function so that I can easily transform it to JSON. Also this line of code is still not working because the compiler is telling me to use `Await` object instead.

Also for PropertyType I need to do the same thing as for currencies.

What is the best way to obtain the desired result?

I am in the learning phase so I don't get much of this.

**LATER EDIT**: the flow is: request -> getDictionaries -> dictionaryService.getDictionaries -> dictionaryDAO.getCurrencies&PropertyTypes

It seems to me that I need to get them in a synchronized way.

The purpose of this is to not create a request for each type of dictionary. If I have 10 dictionaries, I want to get all of them in one request.

**Later EDIT 2**

This is my working example which does not look very well:

Controller:

```
  def getDictionaries = Action.async { implicit request =>
    dictionaryService.getDictionaries.map {
      dictionaries => Ok(Json.toJson(dictionaries))
    }
  }
```

DictionaryService:

```
  override def getDictionaries : Future[Dictionaries] = {
    dictionaryDao.getCurrencies.flatMap { currencies =>
      dictionaryDao.getPropertyTypes.flatMap { propertyTypes =>
        Future.successful(Dictionaries(
          currencies,
          propertyTypes
        ))
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getDictionaries` should return `Future[Dictionaries]`:

```
override def getDictionaries : Future[Dictionaries] = {
    val futureCurrencies = dictionaryDao.getCurrencies
    futureCurrencies map { currencies => // currencies is here Seq[Currency]
      Dictionaries(
        currencies,
        List(PropertyType(1, "x"))
    )
  }
```

And your controller method:

```
def getDictionaries = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val futureDictionaries = dictionaryService.getDictionaries
    futureDictionaries map { dictionaries =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(dictionaries))
    }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**: You have to use `Future`s all the way bottom up if you want your actions to be *really* asynchronous. You'll have to learn how to compose them with `map`, `flatMap` and `for comprehension`s. I didn't find any gentle and short introduction for that, you'll have to search it by yourself. Basically, when you `map` over `Future`, you are transforming it's(successful) result, and thus getting another `Future`. With `flatMap` you can have some ordering of futures, like: when `f1` finishes, start `f2` etc...

Comment: Will this really work because I am transforming an Object with futures of something into a json. Will this be transformed correctly? From my understanding your solution is telling me to store in my Dictionaries object some Future of Dictionary.

Comment: Yes, you need to propagate the future all the way to the controller, if you want your actions to be async indeed. Your solution is kind of half way, when you call this line: `currencies.result(Duration(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` you actually block your thread, wait for future's termination.

Comment: I have a feeling that you misunderstood me. I updated my code, please take a short look.

Comment: Also I added a few explanations at the end.

Comment: I managed to make it work but I am not very proud of the result. Please take a look.